# Java, Spark, return index.html

Tags: java, spark-java

I'm trying to create SPA, using Spark on server-side.
Here is my App.java:

```
package com.farot;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import static spark.Spark.*;

import com.farot.utils.Path;

import com.farot.controllers.UserController;
import com.farot.controllers.AccountController;
import com.farot.controllers.MapController;

public class App 
{
  private static Gson gson = new Gson();

  private static String renderIndex() {
    try {
      URL url = App.class.getResource("index.html");
      return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(url.toURI())), Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    staticFiles.location("/public");

    before((req, res) -> {
      String path = req.pathInfo();
      if (path.endsWith("/"))
        res.redirect(path.substring(0, path.length() - 1));
    });

    // Site pages
    get("/", "text/html", (req, res) -> renderIndex());
    get("/login", "text/html", (req, res) -> renderIndex());

    post(Path.Web.api.Account.DEFAULT, (req, res) -> { 
      return AccountController.create(req, res); 
    }, gson::toJson);

  }

}
```

POST request at Path.Web.api.Account.DEFAULT works as expected, but request at /login returns 404. What can be wrong? 
index.html's path is /resources/public/index.html.

Comment: Are you sure the error you're getting is 404 and not 500?

Comment: yes, it's 404 error. here is console output: [qtp199089828-23] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/login] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image‌​/webp,/;q=0.8]

Comment: How do you perform the get request to `/login`?

Comment: just open localhost:4567/login in my browser.

Comment: What happens if you're defining your route like this: `get("/login", "text/html", (req, res) -> "yo");` ?

Comment: it returns "yo" in browser

Comment: OK. In the `renderIndex()` method - is any exception caught? Also - what Spark version is it?

Comment: spark version is 2.5.4. no any errors in console

Comment: I've just tried to execute this code myself - your exact code gives me error 500, not 404. The only reason I see to get 404 is if the `renderIndex()` returned `null`. But in your scenario `url` is `null` (since index.html has a wrong path) and then an exception is thrown out of the function (you don't catch it since you catch only `IOException | URISyntaxException` and it's neither of these).

Comment: Can you run your code after fixing `index.html` path to the right one? Print `url` in order to be sure it's not `null`.

Comment: here is a result of URL url = App.class.getResource("/public/index.html"); System.out.println(url); : jar:file:/home/gorrtack/workspace/Farot/target/Farot-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/public/index.html

Comment: And does the get request to `/login` work now?

Comment: no, still 404 error

Comment: There's something wrong with `renderIndex()`, you should debug it. Before `return new String(..` define `String str = new String(...` and then print it before you return. What's printed?

Comment: I debug it step-by-step now. This code `System.out.println(url.toURI());
      System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
      System.out.println(Paths.get(url.toURI()));` just prints first and second output, not third. Probably, problem in Paths.get() step.

Comment: Now I understand what's going on, and BTW - you do catch an exception, although you thought you didn't. See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the function `renderIndex()`. After using the correct resource path (i.e. `/public/index.html`) the variable `url` is not null anymore, but according to what you said in the comments it's something weird (`jar:file:/home/gorrtack/workspace/Farot/target/Farot-1.0-SNA‌PSHOT-jar-with-depen‌​dencies.jar!/public/‌​index.html`), something with no valid **path**.

When `Paths.get()` tries to resolve this path it fails and throws a `NoSuchFileException` (which is an `IOException`). Then, you *catch* it in the `catch` block, and **returns null**. The returning of null is wrong and it's the reason for the error 404 you're getting.

So you need:

1. To change something in the structure of your project so the path of `index.html` is right. Then you'll avoid the problems in this scenario.
2. Handle the exceptions correctly, means - **don't return null**. Decide what you want to do in these cases and then, if you want, you can still serve a normal error message to the client and/or use `request.status()` API or any [any other response APIs](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#response) to set a response status by yourself.

Comment: thanks, but I get this path from method `App.class.getResource()` which should be correct. I use maven for building my project and all file structure is like they recommend: **root** -> **src** -> **main** -> separation on **java** with the .java files and **resources** where I keep all static files for frontend-part of my application.

Comment: Seems like the structure is good. But then again, in my project (also maven, same structure) I get the right path from `App.class.getResource()`. Maybe check the pom.xml configuration?

Comment: inside **resources** folder I have **public**. And if I put hello.txt in the public folder, it's available in localhost:4567/hello.txt, because of `staticFiles.location("/public");` in my code. pom configuration is https://github.com/Koroffin/farot/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I've just git cloned your project and added the code from your question and everything works as expected. It's really interesting to understand what you're doing differently...

Comment: it was no actual, without last commits. now I updated the project

Comment: index.html returns at / route, because it serves from public folder. but not routes /game /registration and so on

Answer (score 1):

In the renderIndex() method, access the path as below:

`URL url = App.class.getResource("/public/index.html");`

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't explain the 404 error. It should have been 500 if that was the case.

Comment: it's still 404 error. here is console output: [qtp199089828-23] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/login] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8]

Comment: What are you using to make the Post call?

Comment: Just FYI... u cannot use browser to make the post call directly, you have to use a form submission and make the post call or use POSTMAN or anything else